# Long holiday in Spain, UK citizen with German husband

Tags: spain, uk-citizens, long-stay-visas, german-citizens

I am German, my wife is British. Normally I could go on a holiday to Spain for any amount of time, and my wife could go for up to three months.

Would it be possible for my wife to stay more than three months (most likely less than six) together with me? Would she need to apply for a visitor visa, or apply through EU free movement laws? If it is difficult, would it be possible to go from Spain to Portugal, Italy or Greece, or is the three month limit for the whole Schengen area?

(If it is important: This would be between the sale of a house and buying a new one, so we would have no home address at that point).

Comment: Are the house you (will have) sold and the house you (will) buy in the Schengen area outside Germany? Or will you be a tourist in the Schengen area outside Germany without a fixed address in your usual home country which is different from the countries you visit between the houses.

Comment: Should have made that clearer: I will be selling a house in the UK, and buying another house in the UK shortly later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even as a German, if you are in Spain for longer than three months you need to register with the Spanish authorities - which, for an EU citizen, means applying for a "[Certificado de Registro de Ciudadano de la Unión](https://sede.policia.gob.es/portalCiudadano/_es/tramites_extranjeria_tramite_certificadoregistro_ciudadanoue.php#)". As you mention you are there for property transactions, I assume that you already have a NIE (*Número de Identifiación de Extranjero*, a foreigner's ID number) - the Certificado is the "green NIE" and [looks like this](https://www.barcelona.cat/internationalwelcome/en/certificate-of-registration-as-an-eu-national), as opposed to the "white NIE" which you get for ID purposes but which doesn't give you any residency rights in Spain beyond 90 days, and which [looks like this](https://www.barcelona.cat/internationalwelcome/en/identity-number-for-foreign-nationals-nie).

Once you have that Certificado de Registro, though, your wife would be entitled to join you as a [family member of a Union citizen](https://www.inclusion.gob.es/web/migraciones/w/tarjeta-de-residencia-de-familiar-de-ciudadano-de-la-union-europe-hi-102-). She would need to apply for a residence permit at a foreigners' office or police station, but generally this should be granted without issue as long as you have the green NIE (ie as long as you are a resident).

However, you say that you wouldn't have a home address - for this residency you would need to be on the Padrón de Habitantes (the Spanish equivalent of the Melderegister) somewhere. If this wouldn't be possible then I would imagine that you would have difficulty in applying for residency, but you'd probably need legal advice at that point.

Travelling to different countries gets you around the 90 day limit before you have to register in a country, and as long as your wife is travelling with you (as an EU citizen) then the 90 day limit for staying in the Schengen area [doesn't apply either](https://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/travel/entry-exit/non-eu-family/index_en.htm) - quoting from that site under "Length of Stay":

> If your non-EU family members have the required documents, they are entitled to accompany or join you without any conditions or formalities for consecutive periods of up to 3 months per EU country visited. They are not subject to the overall limitation of up to 90 days in a 180-day period that applies in the Schengen area. You can combine stays in different EU countries without an overall time-limit (as long as the conditions of the EU rules on residence are met).

Comment: "Once you have that Certificado de Registro, though, your wife would be entitled to join you as a family member of a Union citizen": The family member of a union citizen is entitled to those rights regardless of administrative formalities.  Similarly, the EU citizen has a right to reside for longer than three months independent of the administrative formalities.  The certificate of registration does not confer the right to reside for longer than three months, and failing to obtain the certificate cannot result in expulsion.